# Read active pagenumber in pdf with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I'm about to embed a .pdf file in a HTML document and I want the surrounding frame to change to a specific color for each page the user scrolls by.

`The document loads at page 1 and the javascript should return '1' - Then the user scrolls down to page 2 and the javascript should return '2'`

I'm quite sure Adobe's Reader plugin is not capable of this and I can't seem to find any documentation for eg. PDF.js that describes such a function.

The question has been answered for `#C` earlier so I'm pretty sure it must possible with javascript to.

Comment: If I understand the PDF.js documentation that answer referes to opening a specific page in a PDF file - not returning the current pagenumber when scrolling. Please correct me if wrong.

Comment: If you end up going with pdf.js take a look at the pdf_viewer.js sample. The current page is the visible page. https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/c42613b9110a332fc8028f263ae73380ec8272ca/web/pdf_viewer.js#L127